# Using RegEx to ignore empty strings and spaces

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string

I have the following simple test which doesnt return true for some reason.

```
string[] test = new string[] { "A", " ", " ", "D", "" };
Regex reg = new Regex(@"^[A-Z]\s$");
bool ok = test.All(x => reg.IsMatch(x));
```

I've also tried putting the \s inside the square brackets but that doesn't work either

I want to make sure that all characters in the array that are not empty or blank spaces match A-Z.

I realise I could do a Where(x=>!String.IsNullorEmpty(x) && x != " ") before the All but I thought Regex could handle this scenario

Comment: In .Net 4 you also have String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace which removes the need for && x != " ".  Can't help with regex though, sorry (I suck at it)

Comment: Please try to be clear about where you mean strings, and where you mean characters: "All characters in the array that are not empty strings" - characters and strings aren't the same thing.

Comment: @Jon: It's still not clear what you mean, because you've got an array of *strings*. I think it would really help if you could reduce your example to matching a *single* string. Once you've worked out how to get a single string to work how you want, you can move on to match multiple strings with `All` trivially.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want:

```
Regex reg = new Regex(@"^[A-Z\s]*$");
```

That basically says "the string consists entirely of whitespace or A-Z".

If you want to force it to be a single character or empty, just change it to:

```
Regex reg = new Regex(@"^[A-Z\s]?$");
```

Comment: Do you mean it will ignore the whitespace ie/it wont try and match against those elements

Comment: @Jon: I don't know what you mean. It won't *ignore* the whitespace - it'll *match* the whitespace. So "A B C" will match the first regex, as will "A   ", but "A0" won't.

Comment: I think I need to do the Where clause to strip the whitespace and empties because the All will run over every element

Comment: @Jon: It's still not clear what you're trying to do. The first regular expression will match whitespace and empty strings too, so you don't need to strip them out first.

Comment: @Jon-not-Skeet: If you add the line `Console.WriteLine(ok);` to the code in your question, then using either of the regexes in this answer, the output is `True`.  Isn't that what you want?

Comment: What I want it to do is to do a check on the elements in the array that dont have whitespace and are not empty so if all elements are empty or contains whitespace it returns false. This is why I think I need to do a Where clause

Comment: @Jon: It would be really helpful if you'd describe what you're trying to do in the question, without reference to code but *with* plenty of examples. Be as precise as you can. For example, when you say "contains whitespace" do you actually mean "entirely composed of whitespace"?

Answer (score 1):

[`Enumerable.All<TSource> Method`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541.aspx) Determines whether **all** elements of a sequence satisfy a condition.

Comment: Yup I think I need the Where clause!

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression `^[A-Z]\s$` says: two-character string, whose first character is `A-Z` and the second is a white space. What you actually want is `^[A-Z\s]*$`.